# Structs strange behavior

Tags: go, struct

I just started to play with Go-lang and come across a Strange behavior of it Structs. I have a Struct `A` and another Struct `B`, in Struct `B` one key defined as `[]A` the problem is when assigning the value of new instance type of `B` as elements of `A` it throw error despite the types are same. Any help will be greatly appreciated
Below here I am pasting the minimal code which cause error

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/disk"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    /************ disk details goes here ************/
    diskPartitions, err := disk.Partitions(true)
    dealwithErr(err)
    fmt.Println(diskPartitions)

    type PARTITIONLIST []PARTITION
    var partitionsList PARTITIONLIST

    for partitionIndex, partition := range diskPartitions {
        partitionStat, err := disk.Usage(partition.Mountpoint)
        dealwithErr(err)

        var partitionDetails = PARTITION{
            "PARTITION",
            partitionIndex,
            partition.Mountpoint,
            "" + fmt.Sprint(partitionStat.Total) + " and " + bytesToSize(partitionStat.Total),
            "" + fmt.Sprint(partitionStat.Used) + " and " + bytesToSize(partitionStat.Used),
            "" + fmt.Sprint(partitionStat.Free) + " and " + bytesToSize(partitionStat.Free),
            "" + fmt.Sprint(partitionStat.UsedPercent) + "and " + strconv.FormatFloat(partitionStat.UsedPercent, 'f', 2, 64),
        }

        partitionsList = append(partitionsList, partitionDetails)
    }

    //till here working fine
    fmt.Println(partitionsList)

    //THE BELOW TWO LINES ERROR IS THE ACTUAL ERROR I AM ASKING
    var partitionDetails = PARTITIONS{
        "partitions",
        partitionsList
    }



    dealwithErr(err)
}

/************ all struct goes here ************/

type PARTITION struct {
    Name                   string
    Partition_index        int
    Partition              string
    Total_space_in_bytes   string
    Used_space_in_bytes    string
    Free_space_in_bytes    string
    Percentage_space_usage string
}

type PARTITIONLIST []PARTITION

type PARTITIONS struct {
    Name                string
    List                []PARTITIONS
}

/************ helper functions goes below here ************/
func bytesToSize(bytes uint64) string {
    sizes := []string{"Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"}
    if bytes == 0 {
        return fmt.Sprint(float64(0), "bytes")
    } else {
        var bytes1 = float64(bytes)
        var i = math.Floor(math.Log(bytes1) / math.Log(1024))
        var count = bytes1 / math.Pow(1024, i)
        var j = int(i)
        var val = fmt.Sprintf("%.1f", count)
        return fmt.Sprint(val, sizes[j])
    }
}

func dealwithErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: that error am getting on run time

> unexpected newline, expecting comma or }

and that warning editor show on IDE

> Cannot use partitionsList (type PARTITIONSLIST) as type []PARTITIONS

Comment: Note that all structs working until I start using `slices` to generate dynamic partitions list

Comment: Your question is unnecessarily confusing. There's no A and B struct in your code, so just use the names you have in your code so it is clear what you talk about. Also, if you have an error, copy paste that error so we can see it.

Comment: @AbdulHameed Please post the error you are getting. Because I think it is due to mismatch types.

Comment: Actually it's very big single file. I just posted code sample which generate error

Comment: @AbdulHameed thing is that what I am able to see is you have mismatch type.

Comment: @Himanshu I updated the question with both error messages

Comment: You're missing a comma right behind `partitionsList` in the declaration of `var partitionDetails = PARTITIONS{...`

Comment: @AbdulHameed consider learning basics before starting to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error clearly says:

> Cannot use partitionsList (type PARTITIONSLIST) as type []PARTITIONS

You have type mismatch problem in the struct. Since PARTITIONSLIST is not qualy to []PARTITIONS. So if you create variable of both types they are different.

```
type PARTITIONLIST []PARTITION

type PARTITIONS struct {
    Name                string
    List                []PARTITIONS // here the list is slice of Partitions.
}
```

While when you are creating a slice of PARTITIONLIST type.

```
var partitionsList PARTITIONLIST // this is a variable of PARTITIONLIST type which is not equal to `[]PARTITIONS`
```

This is because golang is strictly typed language. So even if the underlying type of both values are similar. The are still different. To be more simple Try this example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyInt int

func main() {
    var a int = 2
    var b MyInt = 2
    fmt.Println(a==b)
}
```

**Output:**

> invalid operation: a == b (mismatched types int and MyInt)

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/inYjRqqr7hI)

So you need to create a slice of `[]PARTITIONS` as:

```
var partitionsList `[]PARTITIONS`
```

or you can create both variables of `PARTITIONLIST` type to make them similar.

Another error:

> unexpected newline, expecting comma or }

is because you need to pass `,` after last field if you are using it in new line as:

```
var partitionDetails = PARTITIONS{
    "partitions",
    partitionsList, // pass comma here in your code.
}
```

Full working example :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/disk"
)

func main() {

    /************ disk details goes here ************/
    diskPartitions, err := disk.Partitions(true)
    dealwithErr(err)
    fmt.Println(diskPartitions)

    var partitionsList PARTITIONLIST

    for partitionIndex, partition := range diskPartitions {
        partitionStat, err := disk.Usage(partition.Mountpoint)
        dealwithErr(err)

        var partitionDetails = PARTITION{
            "PARTITION",
            partitionIndex,
            partition.Mountpoint,
            "" + fmt.Sprint(partitionStat.Total) + " and " + bytesToSize(partitionStat.Total),
            "" + fmt.Sprint(partitionStat.Used) + " and " + bytesToSize(partitionStat.Used),
            "" + fmt.Sprint(partitionStat.Free) + " and " + bytesToSize(partitionStat.Free),
            "" + fmt.Sprint(partitionStat.UsedPercent) + "and " + strconv.FormatFloat(partitionStat.UsedPercent, 'f', 2, 64),
        }

        partitionsList = append(partitionsList, partitionDetails)
    }

    //till here working fine
    fmt.Println(partitionsList)

    //THE BELOW TWO LINES ERROR IS THE ACTUAL ERROR I AM ASKING
    var partitionDetails = PARTITIONS{
        "partitions",
        partitionsList,
    }

    fmt.Println(partitionDetails)

    dealwithErr(err)
}

/************ all struct goes here ************/

type PARTITION struct {
    Name                   string
    Partition_index        int
    Partition              string
    Total_space_in_bytes   string
    Used_space_in_bytes    string
    Free_space_in_bytes    string
    Percentage_space_usage string
}

type PARTITIONLIST []PARTITION

type PARTITIONS struct {
    Name string
    List PARTITIONLIST
}

/************ helper functions goes below here ************/
func bytesToSize(bytes uint64) string {
    sizes := []string{"Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"}
    if bytes == 0 {
        return fmt.Sprint(float64(0), "bytes")
    } else {
        var bytes1 = float64(bytes)
        var i = math.Floor(math.Log(bytes1) / math.Log(1024))
        var count = bytes1 / math.Pow(1024, i)
        var j = int(i)
        var val = fmt.Sprintf("%.1f", count)
        return fmt.Sprint(val, sizes[j])
    }
}

func dealwithErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/v4Q3YMW-LvA)

Comment: When the underlying type is same, you can assign it, [example](https://play.golang.org/p/87Y1b8zL6cL)

Comment: @nilsocket no you cannot Because go is strict. What you are doing is you are not creating a variable of different type. You are creating a variable of primitive type.

Comment: @nilsocket is there online example for `golang` like jsfiddle for javascript where you post working the above one

Comment: Here is the updated [example](https://play.golang.org/p/fjQs8zfEaxU), one cannot pass it to function but can assign it in struct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, reading [this](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html?#names) and change your naming style,

Take time to decide what would be proper names.

you have declared `PARITIONLIST` twice

```
type PARTITIONLIST []PARTITION //17th line, remove this
```

`PARTITIONS` is defined as,

```
type PARTITIONS struct {
    Name string
    List []PARTITION
}
```

you can use `PARTITIONLIST` instead of `[]PARTITION` type for `List` field.

A struct variable field values are ended with comma,

```
var partitionDetails = PARTITIONS{
        "partitions",
        partitionsList,
    }
```

Comment: @AbdulHameed, as said change, type `PARTITIONS` field `List` to  `PARTITIONLIST` type instead of `[]PARTITION`. Consider reading answer carefully.